# How browsers render html table cells with set width to 100%

Tags: html, css, html-table

I trying to understand how browsers render table cells with width set to 100%. How they calculate the width of cells. We have the following example

```html
<table style="width: 100%; color: black">
        <tr>
            <td>
                AAAA
            </td>
            <td>
                <div style="width: 100%;height: 25px; background: red;"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Output is weird

[image]

My question is why the first cell is that long (it contains only 4 letters of text  and should end after last letter) while the second cells width should be as wide as possible.

I would expect something like that

[image]

Comment: If you want the second cell to take up the majority of the table's width, why aren't you styling that instead of the cell's content?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't set any width for the `td`s, the proportion between them is analog to the content. In your example, four letters in the first cell is infinite times more content than the second cell has (no text at all).

If you want to avoid that, define width settings for the `td`s - see the example below - once with your original code, once with added content in the first `td`

```css
td {
width: 50%; 
}
```

```html
<table style="width: 100%; color: black">
        <tr>
            <td>
                AAAA
            </td>
            <td>
                <div style="width: 100%;height: 25px; background: red;"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

```css
td {
width: 50%; 
}
```

```html
<table style="width: 100%; color: black">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.</p>

<p>In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus.</p>

<p>Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div style="width: 100%;height: 25px; background: red;"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: so if width is along to the content why first cell is that long? he contain only 4 letters and he should end after last letter. Why he have width about almost 80%

Comment: because of its *content* (the letters). the other cell has *no* content... Please read my answer

Comment: But content of first cell (the letters) is not long up to about 90% of table.  More or less it is about 5%. The second cell should be that long as he can. Beacuse its content (red div with width set to 100%) should be rest of table width

Comment: In the second cell you have set 100% width to the *DIV*. But that means this DIV has 100% width of the TD it is in, and that one is very narrow since it has no width setting. If you want to change that, give 100% width to the cell (TD), not to the DIV inside it.